# Can I apply for a Schengen visa from my home country when I have a residence permit in another country?

Tags: schengen, india, china, spain

I am a Chinese citizen holding a valid Chinese passport and currently in China. However I have a residence permit (X visa) in India as my husband is Indian.

Is it true that I can only apply for a Schengen visa from India and cannot apply at the Spanish embassy in China?

Comment: @ThisIsMyName *You* are absolutely wrong. You can usually not apply for a Schengen visa from the country of citizenship if you do not reside there.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo the problem is that i do reside in my country of citizenship, all my utilities, bank account, residential address is in China. How can i prove that i reside in China irrespective of the residential permit. The residential permit i have to make it easy to travel to my husbands country without needing to apply for a visa every time.

Answer (score 3):

You must apply to the Spanish consulate that is competent for your place of residence. It is not clear from your question where that is.

If you actually live and reside in India and are just on a short visit to China, you will not be able to get a visa from a Spanish consulate in China, but will have to apply at the consulate competent for your place of residence in India.

If you live and reside in China (being in possession of an Indian residence permit then becomes irrelevant), you must apply at the consulate competent for your place of residence in China.

The Schengen visa code provides some exceptions to this general rule, but the consulates are usually very strict in their interpretation.

Comment: How do consulate define place of residence, I just have the residence permit in India, so that i can freely travel to India. However all my residence related things, bank accounts, utilities, residential address is in China. This is the reason i am unsure about applying in India, as i will not have proper documents to produce. However consulate rejected my visa application saying that, if the residence permit is stamped in my passport i need to apply in India, no matter what. What proof can i show that can show i reside in china ? Thanks in advance

Comment: can you point me towards where i can find the Schengen visa code ?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not true. You should apply in the country where you are a resident.

Comment: This answer is not clear as it stands, 'no' so she can apply from China, but also 'you have to apply where you are resident' which is India.

Comment: @Willeke Based on "_currently in China_" I presume that OP resides in China.

Comment: Currently can be a few weeks or even less which is not a residency, or a few months, which is.

Comment: I arrived in China on 12th of January, before that i did stay in India for 6 months, but this was directly related to my marriage (aka i married in this time). Given that all my utilities like bank account, residential address is in China, am i still considered to be a resident in India. I find it confusing, because if i am to submit the application in India, i will have to end up submitting my Chinese bank statement which is obviously in Chinese, which i am not sure they will even accept.